# Java- Trouble understanding java threads

Tags: java

I have been working with threads and i came upon a piece of code which was hard for me to understand, i have been trying to search on google but come up with nothing that could really make me comprehend it. This is the code. So the hard part to understand about this for me is two lines. its index = (index + 1) % messages.length; and SwingUtilities.invokeLater( new Write(messages[index]) );. Could somebody please explain when and why swingutilites is used and what index = (index + 1) % messages means. Btw  messages is an array of strings

```
public void run() {
  while( argumentsOK && !interrupted()) {
    // UI-tråden ska användas
    SwingUtilities.invokeLater( new Write(messages[index]) );
    index = (index + 1) % messages.length;
    try {
      Thread.sleep(pause);
    } catch(InterruptedException e) {
      break;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: This not a complete code. Where is `index` declared? `%` is a Modulus Operator in Java. I believe this snippet has more to do with a specific implementation rather than anything complex to do with threads and synchronization. For example how much is `pause`?

Comment: Sorry, i didnt think those details were necessary. I was merely trying to understand what those codes do. Pause is just 1000ms or whatever delay you want the message to be shown. And index is declared 0 at start of class and it increments everytime there index is less than the arrays length.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's hard to know for sure what is going on here since you don't provide all the involved code, including the definition of **messages**.  But I'll try to answer your two questions with what I can see:

SwingUtilities.invokeLater() is a method used when writing a Swing GUI in a multithreaded application.  Certain things, like most things that cause drawing, have to occur in the main dispatch thread of a Swing application.  invokeLater() is used when code running in another thread than the dispatch thread wants to do something that can only be done in the dispatch thread.  It says to Swing "run this code when you can in the dispatch thread".

what's going on with 'messages' and '% messages.length' appears to be some sort of ring buffer, where so many messages are kept in a list, and when processing of the end of the list is reached, the processing restarts at the beginning of the list.

Comment: Thank you for your anser! And what you wrote about message is correct. It says that the messages will be restarted but i dont understand how the code works with "'%".

Comment: '%' is the modulo operator.  It causes numbers to stay within a range of 0 to (N - 1), where N is the argument to '%'.  As one quantity keeps increasing without bound, the modulo of that quantity will continually cycle between 0 and N-1, going from the value N-1 back to 0 and starting over.  It's like the "remainder" when you divide one integer by another.  2 % 5, 7 % 5 and 12 % 5 all have a value of '2', as that's the remainder when you divide 2, 7 and 12 by 5.  - The modulo 3 of the sequence (0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8) is (0, 1, 2, 0, 1, 2, 0, 1, 2)